# How can bind data to repeater control in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I am binding data to repeater control from database of company. I am trying to fetch company name from database and want to show as label, but it is not working.

My `C#` code is:

```
string conn_string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UPOneConn"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn_string);
con.Open();
string ComSelectCompanyDataStr = "Select Company_Name from Company_Details where Company_ID = '8' ";
SqlCommand ComSelectCompanyData = new SqlCommand(ComSelectCompanyDataStr, con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = ComSelectCompanyData;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
Repeater1.Visible = true;   
con.Close();
```

and my design code:

```
<div id="company_container">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%# Eval ("Company_Name") %></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>            
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add:

```
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

after

```
Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
```

So:

```
Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

And your repeater hes not any item in its ItemTemplate?
You should set that like:

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval ("Company_Name") %></td>
            </tr>            
        </ItemTemplate>
```

And you sql query has bad syntax (If company id is int).

change that to this:

```
"Select Company_Name from Company_Details where Company_ID = 8";
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and i  already tried this but Still not working. @FarzinKanzi

Comment: @Rahul Describe "not working". Is your code reached? Have you debugged to verify your objects are populated properly?

Comment: "not working" mean Label1 not taking the value of Company_Name from data source. When i am printing only company name by Response.Write() it is printing the company name but when i am going to use Repeater control and trying to get the text of Label1 as company name then it's not taking the company name, remains blank or null.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi  ...Ohhh it is showing count 0, so what should i  do now? Please Help.. Thanks

Comment: Probably you have not a record with Company_ID = '8'. change your sql query and remove 'where' filter to get all of the records.

Comment: No, i have record for this id, and i am recording the selected data in a string and when i am only printing the company name using Response.Write(mystring) it printing the correct name.

Comment: The label you're binding to Company_Name is in the HeaderTemplate: it should be in the ItemTemplate

Comment: Change this Repeater1.DataSource = dt to this: Repeater1.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];(It is a guess only).

Comment: Firstly i said you that you mast put your records in item template.